# Download / Update Online file using Lua 5.1

Tags: android, download, lua, auto-update

I am using Lua V5.1 32 bit version. I was wondering if it is possible to have Lua code to download and update a file

E.g whatever file is in this file path be downloaded to the same directory as the Lua file is in. Thanks

https://www.mediafire.com/download/xv40koc4yi2p47d

I have looked at a couple of Q + A's, but I have like no idea what they are on about, so for the purposes of this, can you think I am a complete beginner to Lua, and include all importing modules... Thanks

Comment: We have no tag "ankulua"...

Comment: Egor- I am using this thing on android called ANKULUA to create bots, non root, but coding in Lua, I mentioned above the version it runs, so yes it is android- specific, however since it is using the Lua language, all syntax still works!